# NodeJs - Youtube Notifer - DiscordBot

Tags: javascript, node.js, youtube, youtube-api

I am trying at the moment to fix and error, that happend after after a dependency Update.
Since my knowlegde is limited about javascript, I used the code from this project: https://github.com/Androz2091/DiscordYoutubeNotifier
I mainly changed the formating and translation.

RssURL: https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCswEIUl5D05V1jb9Dv5rVMw

This is the code:

```
//YOUTUBE
//https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started


/**
 * Format a date to a readable string
 * @param {Date} date The date to format 
 */
function formatDate(date) {
    let monthNames = [ "Januar", "Februar", "März", "April", "Mai", "Juni", "Juli", "August", "September", "Oktober", "November", "Dezember" ];
    let day = date.getDate(), month = date.getMonth(), year = date.getFullYear();
    return `${day} ${monthNames[parseInt(month, 10)]} ${year}`;
}

/**
 * Call a rss url to get the last video of a youtuber
 * @param {string} youtubeChannelName The name of the youtube channel
 * @param {string} rssURL The rss url to call to get the videos of the youtuber
 * @returns The last video of the youtuber
 */
async function getLastVideo(youtubeChannelName, rssURL){
    //console.log(`[${youtubeChannelName}]  | Getting videos...`);
    
    let content = await parser.parseURL(rssURL)
      .then(content => {
            let tLastVideos = content.items.sort((a, b) => {
                let aPubDate = new Date(a.pubDate || 0).getTime();
                let bPubDate = new Date(b.pubDate || 0).getTime();
                return bPubDate - aPubDate;
            });
            //console.log(`[${youtubeChannelName}]  | The last video is "${tLastVideos[0] ? tLastVideos[0].title : "err"}"`);
            return tLastVideos[0];
         })
      .catch();
      //.catch(console.error);
}

/**
 * Check if there is a new video from the youtube channel
 * @param {string} youtubeChannelName The name of the youtube channel to check
 * @param {string} rssURL The rss url to call to get the videos of the youtuber
 * @returns The video || null
 */
async function checkVideos(youtubeChannelName, rssURL){
    //console.log(`[${youtubeChannelName}] | Get the last video..`);
    let lastVideo = await getLastVideo(youtubeChannelName, rssURL)
      .then(lastVideo => {
           if (lastVideo) {
                // If the date of the last uploaded video is older than the date of the bot starts, return 
                if(new Date(lastVideo.pubDate).getTime() < startAt) return; // console.log(`[${youtubeChannelName}] | Last video was uploaded before the bot starts`);
                let lastSavedVideo = lastVideos[youtubeChannelName];
                // If the last video is the same as the last saved, return
                if(lastSavedVideo && (lastSavedVideo.id === lastVideo.id)) return; // console.log(`[${youtubeChannelName}] | Last video is the same as the last saved`);
                return lastVideo;
           }//else console.log("[ERR] | No video found for " + lastVideo);
         })
      .catch();
     // .catch(console.error);
}

/**
 * Get the youtube channel id from an url
 * @param {string} url The URL of the youtube channel
 * @returns The channel ID || null
 */
function getYoutubeChannelIdFromURL(url) {
    let id = null;
    url = url.replace(/(>|<)/gi, "").split(/(\/channel\/|\/user\/)/);
    if(url[2]) {
      id = url[2].split(/[^0-9a-z_-]/i)[0];
    }
    return id;
}

/**
 * Get infos for a youtube channel
 * @param {string} name The name of the youtube channel or an url
 * @returns The channel info || null
 */
async function getYoutubeChannelInfos(name){
    //console.log(`[${name.length >= 10 ? name.slice(0, 10)+"..." : name}] | Resolving channel infos...`);
    let channel = null;
    /* Try to search by ID */
    let id = getYoutubeChannelIdFromURL(name);
    if(id){
        channel = await youtube.getChannelByID(id);
    }
    if(!channel){
        /* Try to search by name */
        let channels = await youtube.searchChannels(name);
        if(channels.length > 0){
            channel = channels[0];
        }
    }
    //console.log(`[${name.length >= 10 ? name.slice(0, 10)+"..." : name}] | Title of the resolved channel: ${channel.raw ? channel.raw.snippet.title : "err"}`);
    return channel;
}

/**
 * Check for new videos
 */
 //https://tjrgg.github.io/simple-youtube-api/master/Channel.html
async function check(){
    //console.log("Checking...");
    youtubers.forEach(async (youtuber) => {
        //console.log(`[${youtuber.length >= 10 ? youtuber.slice(0, 10)+"..." : youtuber}] | Start checking...`);
        let channelInfos = await getYoutubeChannelInfos(youtuber);
        if(!channelInfos) return console.log("[ERR] | Invalid youtuber provided: "+youtuber);
        let lastVideo = await checkVideos(channelInfos.raw.snippet.title, "https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id="+channelInfos.id);
        if(!lastVideo) return; //console.log(`[${channelInfos.raw.snippet.title}] | No notification`);
        let channel = client.channels.cache.get(youtubeDiscordChannel);
        if(!channel) return console.log("[ERR] | Channel not found");
                
        let video = await youtube.getVideo(lastVideo.link)
         .then(video => {
           if (video) {
               
                const newVidEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
                  .setTitle(':new: ' + video.title)
                  .setDescription(video.description.length > 200 ? video.description.substring(0, 200) + ' ...' : video.description)
                  .setFooter(video.channel.title + ' hat ein neues Video hochgeladen!')
                  .setColor('#FF0040')
                  .setAuthor(video.channel.title)
                  .setImage(video.thumbnails.maxres.url)
                  .setURL(video.url)
                  .setTimestamp(video.publishedAt);
                  
                 channel.send(newVidEmbed);
                 
                console.log("Youtube Notification sent!");
                lastVideos[channelInfos.raw.snippet.title] = video;
           }else console.log('video not found :(');
         })
         .catch();
         //.catch(console.error);
    });
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

and this the error:

```
Error: aborted
[90m    at connResetException (node:internal/errors:683:14)[39m
[90m    at TLSSocket.socketCloseListener (node:_http_client:407:19)[39m
[90m    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:406:35)[39m
[90m    at node:net:662:12[39m
[90m    at TCP.done (node:_tls_wrap:580:7)[39m {
  code: [32m'ECONNRESET'[39m
}
Error: aborted
[90m    at connResetException (node:internal/errors:683:14)[39m
[90m    at TLSSocket.socketCloseListener (node:_http_client:407:19)[39m
[90m    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:406:35)[39m
[90m    at node:net:662:12[39m
[90m    at TCP.done (node:_tls_wrap:580:7)[39m {
  code: [32m'ECONNRESET'[39m
}
Error: aborted
[90m    at connResetException (node:internal/errors:683:14)[39m
[90m    at TLSSocket.socketCloseListener (node:_http_client:407:19)[39m
[90m    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:406:35)[39m
[90m    at node:net:662:12[39m
[90m    at TCP.done (node:_tls_wrap:580:7)[39m {
  code: [32m'ECONNRESET'[39m
}
/path/Master-Bot/node_modules/rss-parser/lib/parser.js:88
          return reject(new Error("Status code " + res.statusCode));
                        ^

Error: Status code 404
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/home/minecraft/DiscordBots/Master-Bot/node_modules/[4mrss-parser[24m/lib/parser.js:88:25)
[90m    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:514:26)[39m
[90m    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:394:28)[39m
[90m    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (node:_http_client:621:27)[39m
[90m    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (node:_http_common:127:17)[39m
    at HTTPParser.execute (<anonymous>)
[90m    at TLSSocket.socketOnData (node:_http_client:487:22)[39m
[90m    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:394:28)[39m
[90m    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:312:12)[39m
[90m    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:287:9)[39m
[90m    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:226:10)[39m
[90m    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23)[39m
```

Comment: `let content = await parser.parseURL(rssURL)` this particularly throws your error could you attach more information such as the whole XML object you get instead of just showing the parsing function directly? it says that the URL you are trying to parse returns a `404` response

Comment: I added the URL in the question above.
It does work, but it seems, that sometimes it isnt reachable. Maybe because of a small packet lost over the night? 
But even so, it should be possible to catch the 404 issue without a crash of the discord bot.

Comment: It wouldnt be able to parse the URL hence resulting in a process.exit() the package url-parser is responsible for the so called "crash" but I am pretty sure that there is no point when a whole channel disappears from the RSS feed so its impossible for such a big organisation such as youtube to make a feed unavaible per certain times

Comment: Well it could be the way to youtube. Maybe my server provider, that changes for a small second something.

Comment: not really requests dont fail like that

Comment: So you think it is an error from the rss-parser package? Or can I do something about it?
From what I heard so far, it sounds like I cant catch the 404 result.

Comment: It is an error from the rss-parser package which is thrown due to the URL being unavailable you may open an issue on their npm pkg's github repo since the URL seems fine as is right now, you may even consider to switch to `rss-feed-emitter` which is a good alternative for this package